# Menu is not visible in safari

Tags: css, safari, viewport, hidden

Recently I have started working on a website. In that I have created a new menu. The menu is working fine on Chrome, Firefox, etc. but the Safari browser is giving me an error.

The menu is completely hidden on Safari.

My Website link: https://www.destylio.com/

This is how it looks on Chrome:
[Menu in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQBjU.png)

This is how it looks on Safari:
[Menu in Safari is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqXyd.png)

So please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to set your .overlay ul li opacity to 1. Maybe you've got an animation running that's not resetting on load?

```
.overlay ul li {
 opacity:1;
}
```

You use `-webkit-animation: fadeInRight 0s ease forwards;` - I don't think that's running in safari, where it is in chrome. As a result the LI's are being rolled in.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to increase your animation duration time

```
animation: fadeInRight 0s ease forwards;
```

to

```
animation: fadeInRight 0.001s ease forwards;
```